# How to get vertices of a rotated rectangle in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, rectangles, image-rotation

I used `warpAffine` in OpenCV to rotate a rectangle. Now I want to get the four vertices (the x and y locations of four points) of this rotated rectangle without rotating it back. After hours of search, I came up with no result. Could someone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
cv::RotatedRect RotRect;
// Fill in RotRect somehow...

//Get four corners
cv::Point2f pts[4];
RotRect.points(pts);
```

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect) also has an example.